# Adding static method to IronPython scope

Tags: c#-4.0, ironpython

Assume I have the following code:

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static void Bar() {}
}
```

In IronPython, I would like to have:

```
Bar()
```

Without having to include the Foo on the line.  Now, I know I can say:

```
var Bar = Foo.Bar
Bar()
```

But I would like to add Bar to the ScriptScope in my C# code using SetVariable.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create delegate to method and set in to scope.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var python = Python.CreateEngine();
        var scriptScope = python.CreateScope();
        scriptScope.SetVariable("Print", new Action<int>(Bar.Print));

        python.Execute(
            "Print(10)",
            scriptScope
            );
    }

}

public static class Bar
{
    public static void Print(int a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Print:{0}", a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  I tip my bonnet to you.